# How to join lines that end with - but do not start with space in SED?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I am working on sed script that merges adjacent lines of text ending with the - character, if there are no white characters (space, tab) before it, together with the next line.

I have a script that doesn exactly that, however it doesn't filter properly.

My script

```
 #!/bin/bash
 file=$1
 sed ':a;/-$/{N;s/-\n//;ba}' $file
```

This is my file input

```
line1- 
line2

line3-
line4

line5 -
 line6
```

And this is the result I want to see

```
line1- 
line2

line3line4

line5 -
 line6
```

And this is what I get

```
line1- 
line2

line3line4

line5 line6
```

Comment: why do you *not* join `line1-` and `line2` to form `line1line2`?

Comment: are you always dealing with 2-line sets, or could you have 3-, 4-, n-line sets (eg, `line7-`, `line8-`, `line9` => `line7line8line9`?

Comment: what if you have a pair of lines to join but the 2nd line starts with white space (spaces, tabs)? do you remove or keep the leading white space from the 2nd line?

Comment: With GNU sed: `sed -zE 's/-\n([^ ])/\1/' file`

Comment: `printf '%s\n' '1;/[^[:blank:]]-$/,s/-$//' '.;+j' ,p Q | ed -s file.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a pattern to capture a non whitespace char in a group, and use that group in the replacement without using a label:

```
sed -E '/-$/{N;s/([^[:space:]])-\n/\1/}' $file
```

Output

```
line1- 
line2

line3line4

line5 -
 line6
```

See a [sed demo](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzg1RUHXVUFdX1dFv9rPulhfIzou2qq4IDE51So2VlM3Jk8/xlC/Vl3BxsZGQSknMy/VUFeBC0QbcYEpY10wZQLhmSrocimAGGZK//8DAA).

Answer (score 2):

This `sed` command should do the job:

```
sed '
:a
/[^[:blank:]]-$/!b
$!N
s/-\n//
$!ba' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -rz 's/ -\n/ -\r/g; s/-\n//g; s/ -\r/ -\n/g' $file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;N;s/(\S)-\n/\1/;ta;P;D' file
```

Append the following line and if the current line ends in a non-space character followed by a `-`, remove the `-` and the following newline and go again.

Otherwise, print/delete the first line and repeat.